# Create a XML feed with advanced export

Tags: magento-1.9, importexport, dataflow

For our search provider we need a custom xml feed to export category content. So I was thinking of going the advanced profile route. Basically, what I want to create:

```
<item><content_type>category_content</content_type>
  <g:id>6_nl</g:id>
  <title>My interesting info</title>
  <description>This category if filled with interesting information</description>
  <link>https://mywebsite/mycategory</link>
</item>
```

Is there a way to do that? So far all my searches end up with people trying to export product, but this is already covered by the plugins.